# Adding or overriding locales in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, localization

I am looking for a way to add new locale files or override existing ones.

Basically a Craft 3 version of this: https://craftcms.com/support/adding-additional-locales

I've tried the way described here: https://github.com/craftcms/locales

But that does not seem to be picked up by Craft 3.

Comment: You're saying you need to use an additional locale that isn't in this list? https://github.com/craftcms/locales/tree/master/locales That list is generated from the [intl](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension which is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: @BradBell What I need is a combination of the Dutch number notation (decimals / thousands) and the rest of the site can use the English rules. So my idea was putting a duplicate `en.php` file in the `config/locales/` folder with those specific changes to override the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried the way described here: https://github.com/craftcms/locales but that does not seem to be picked up by Craft 3.

Haven't actually tested this, but looking at the code I think it should work.

You'll need to disable the intl extension from being loaded on your box (usually done in php.ini) because if Craft sees that's available, it will use that automatically.

If it's not available, it falls back to `config/locales`, which is where you should be able to put your "custom" locale.